# Post model to controller using ajax jquery in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Can somebody help me how can I post model back to controller using jQuery and ajax.

When I post my form, my controller is receiving an empty model. Please corrent me where I am doing a mistake.

Model:

```
public class AllocateToStore
    {
        public IList<OrderLine> FailureAllocations { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> AllocationStatus
        {
            get
            {
                // code to fetch list.
            }
        }
    }

 public class OrderLine
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AutoAllocate()
        {
// This action will load the view with data.
// Get model data and send it to view.

            return View("Allocated",model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ResolveUnallocatedOrders(AllocateToStore coll)
        {
// When user changes the selection in grid and post the page I need to get the selection // here. So that I can update that record.
            return null;
        }
```

And view is

```
 @model AllocateToStore
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Orders";
    }
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model.FailureAllocations, rowsPerPage: 100);
    }


        if (Model.FailureAllocations.Any())
        {
     <form>
        <div>
            @grid.GetHtml(
                    columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column(columnName: "Order date", header: "Order Date", format: item => item.Order.Date),
                       grid.Column("dropdown", header: "Resolution", format:
                                                                   @<span>
                                                                       @{ var index = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); }
                                                                       @Html.Hidden("FailureAllocations.Index", index)
                                                                       @Html.Hidden("FailureAllocations[" + index + "].Id", (long)item.Id)
                                                                       @Html.DropDownList("FailureAllocations[" + index + "].Status", new SelectList(Model.AllocationStatus, "Value", "Text", item.Status))
                                                                   </span>
                     )
                    ),
                    tableStyle: "expandable-table",
                    htmlAttributes: new { id = "gridFailureAllocations" }
                )
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Resolve" id="resolve-button" />
        </div>
</form>
        }


  @section scripts
{
    <script>
        $("#resolve-button").click(function () {
            debugger;
            alert("here");
            $.ajax({
                url: '/OrderProcessing/ResolveUnallocatedOrders',
                data: $('#form').serialize(),
                type: 'POST'
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Thanks,
Naresh

Comment: your AJAX has no success callback to do anything with respnse data. See API which contains examples  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: yea...I will add it. But as of now my controller is only getting empty model.

Comment: I would ask the same question as @Liam and also you should use @Html.HiddenFor() instead of @Html.Hidden()

Comment: if controller not working..why wsn't that in the description of your problems? Just dumping code into a post and saying "help me" wastes everyone's time

Comment: Sorry Charlie..I missed that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

i did not test this answer .it is just suggestion . please try this way.

```
  $.ajax({
      url: o.url,
      type: 'post',
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      data: {"FailureAllocations ":JSON.stringify(FailureAllocations), "AllocationStatus":JSON.stringify(AllocationStatus)}',
       .  . . . 
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bug here `data: $('#form').serialize(),`

`$('#form')` will select all elements with the id "form".  You form doesn't have an id, so your selector won't be working.  Try changing that line to `data: $('form').serialize(),` and the selector should work.

Alternatively, give your form an id of "form" e.g. `<form id="form">` and the original selector `$('#form')` should work.

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more details on the various jQuery selectors.